# How to tighten a union

Tags: plumbing

I'm installing a pressure value and my union is leaking.

[Video](https://i.imgur.com/p8T49bv.mp4)

Is the secret to solving the leak to tighten it even harder? If so, is it OK to put a pipe wrench somewhere on it? What would be a good place?

Edit: What I assumed was a rubber seal actually looks like a cardboard ring. See picture. Or is it actually a seal that looks and feels like a piece of cardboard?

If it's not a seal, does it need a seal? If not a seal, then what's the sealing mechanism in this union?

[image]

Comment: Usually tighten with tools till it stops leaking.  Tightening with tools is usually only one or two full turns.  Too tight is worst than too loose, replacement of union/pipe.  When using tools/wrenches it is usually better to use two, one to hold pipe, one to turn nut.

Comment: That is not a Union. You hand in the video covers the evidance, but it look like it is the valve that is leaking. You might be able to repair that

Comment: @Ruskes  It's definitely the union shooting up

Comment: Well you have better look at it than me. Was the union with -o-ring or did you use teflon tape

Comment: Looking at it again, is there a rubber seal missing ? It does no look like you can tighten it more, it is already metal on metal

Comment: There was a thin metal gasket built into the pressure valve.

Comment: Actually, my assumption about something being a "gasket" was stupid. I'll edit the post to include more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green thing in the picture is a fiber seal. It does look and feel like cardboard, that's normal. Fiber seals are hard when dry so they're easy to put in, and they expand when wet which makes a good seal. However this means they're single use: once it has been wet and expanded, it can't be reused. And if it is still wet, it'll be soggy and unusable anyway. Thankfully they're extremely cheap.

Anyway, after seeing the video, it looks like you forgot to put in the seal. So, unscrew the nut, then check the mating surfaces on the union are clean (no bits of crud from the water, leftovers of old seals, etc). This part is important because if both mating surfaces aren't flat, it won't seal. Wipe off with a dry rag, then put in the seal. There's only one place it'll fit in.

It isn't necessary to separate both parts of the union very far from each other, you can just push the nut out of the way and slip the joint in.

Then to tighten it, you just put one wrench on the top nut, and one on the bottom nut on the other side of the device. There's no place on the device to grab with a wrench, but that's fine, you'll just tighten both nuts at once.

Always be careful not to make the pipes turn, because that might bend them, crack a solder joint, or unscrew something else at the other end.

If the seal in the other nut is old, it's better to change it too.

Fiber seals are hard, so you'll feel it when it gets squeezed. At that point, give maybe 1/8th extra turn and you're done. It's supposed to feel quite firm.

Rubber joints are a lot softer, so it's difficult to feel the point when it's just right, you have to be careful not to overtighten, otherwise it'll squeeze out of the gap where it's supposed to sit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - *"does it need a seal?"* - Yes it does! The seal will not be the metal thing you saw unless it has a compression ring - which this doesn't since it's not a compression fitting. The green gasket looks like it should be the seal in the union that you're trying to tighten. Was it originally in the union nut? If so, replace it. If not, make sure it's the correct size - it should fit inside the nut touching the threads.
When threading the nut on start it by hand. You can use some thread sealant or teflon tape on the threads. Stabilize the PRV below the nut with a second wrench or clamp. Do it in a spot that won't damage the PRV and won't put pressure on any of the fittings between the stabilizing wrench and the nut you are tightening. Tighten the nut with one wrench while stabilizing the PRV using equal counter pressure with the second wrench.
The fact that your video showed water shooting straight up is a good indication you didn't have a proper seal and it wasn't tight enough.